# Solution in WPF for exporting content of a ListBox control containing many items

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook

I've spent some time creating a GUI tool (using WPF Core) that transforms an excel file into a nice-looking report image to be sent via Outlook.

Rows from excel are first read and set as ListBox items (that correspond to rows read from excel).
Then, RenderTargetBitmap is used to generate an image based on this ListBox control (at 96DPI).

This all looks very nice for a small number of rows, but that number grew unexpectedly. With number of rows, image height increases. When inserting image into a new email, the taller it is, the smaller width it gets by Outlook by default. I tried setting its width to 15.00" (with height scaling up proportionally) and some of the times this worked.
But I realized that Outlook automatically scales images when they pass certain height threshold (after sending):

- 1370x4951 -> 1420x836 (totally deformed);
- 1370x4127 -> 1019x3072 (narrow looking in Outlook email reading pane (takes half of its width), but ratio is kept);
- 1370x2735 -> 1440x2875 (taking full width of Outlook preview pane with maintained aspect ratio, perfect).

I either need a different approach for exporting contents of my ListBox, or a guide on how Outlook treats various image resolutions so that I could somehow hack it into displaying the way I need it to.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: Maybe split the rows across mutliple images instead of just one long image?

Comment: One challenge you may have (in case you are planning on giving this tool to somebody else), is that you are explaining the Outlook behavior based on YOUR screen resolution and YOUR Outlook layout.  Another user might change their default reading/preview pane layout (I know I've changed mine), and my monitor resolution may be different than yours.  Does the image have to be embedded in the Outlook email?  Can you just make it an attachment that the user opens up in their favorite image viewer?

Comment: You may need to be consistent and offer a fixed number of rows per image. (Implying that you may need to generate more than one image depending on the number of rows, of course.)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions - generating multiple images might work, good idea, but I'm aiming for a simpler end user experience (I want to leave as little room for mistake as possible - arranging images manually in wrong order or missing any of them could happen). 

@TamBui also made a good point regarding different resolutions and Outlook layouts - the goal is to have this image embedded in the Outlook email, so having this image scale relatively to available space would be ideal.